# MFC LoadString in dll fails

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a static function in dll which loads string from resource using LoadString(). When I call this function from that dll everything works OK. But, when I call this function from other module (activeX control) LoadString fails with error ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND. I tried with AFX_MANAGE_STATE macro but it didn't help. Does anybody know what could be problem here and what is the solution?

Comment: Which module handle do you pass into LoadString()?

Comment: I don't use module handle explicitly. For example:
CString strTmp;
strTmp.LoadString(IDS_TEMP);

Answer (score 6):

If the string is in a resource of the different dll then you have to set the resource handle from the other module to make it work. Try to set the resource handle using [AfxSetResourceHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff(VS.80).aspx) method.

Comment: I don't use resource handle (I use CString's LoadString). I call LoadString from class/function that belongs to that dll. And then I call that function from activeX.

Comment: @Aleksandar: Unless you pass the module handle into CString::LoadString() it will only search within the current module. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not pass handle to the instance of the module to `LoadString` then it uses default resource handle. Default resource handle by default is set to current module handle. So if you call `LoadString` from module that has required string then all works fine. If you call `LoadString` from other module it could not find required string and you'll get error `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`. You could override it by calling `AfxSetResourceHandle` function.

Or you could explicitly select module with resources by passing resource handle to `LoadString`.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you call AFX_MANAGE_STATE at the beginning of a function so that appropriate (dll or exe) resources are loaded.
See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9d5yh5(VS.80).aspx